# Change a function into CPS, to not use call/cc

Tags: scheme, coroutine, continuations, continuation-passing, callcc

I would like to understand how to implement *coroutines* without `call/cc`.

I began with this little example to understand how to modify a code so that I can use it without `call/cc`:

```
(define x 0)

( + 2 (call-with-current-continuation
  (lambda (cont)
    (set! x cont)
  3)))

(x 4)
```

When I execute the function with the `call/cc` it gives me *5*, then *6* when I execute `(x 4)`.

I use this function to replace the `call/cc` :

```
(define (call/cc-cps f continuation)
   (f continuation continuation))
```

I tried to change this function into CPS (continuation-passing style):

```
(call/cc-cps
  (lambda (exit cont)
   (set! x cont)
   3)
(lambda (value)
  (+ value 2)))
```

But when I execute it, instead of having *5* I get *3*. But I do get *6* with `(x 4)`.

Can you tell me what is wrong ? 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CPS you don't have top level continuations prompts so for a comparison you need to put you code in an empty let like this:

```
(let ()
  (define x 0)
  (+ 2 (call-with-current-continuation
         (lambda (cont)
           (set! x cont)
           3))) ; ==> 5
  (x 4))
  ; ==> 6
  ; ==> 6
  ; ==> 6
  ; ... forever
```

This becomes an infinite loop since you call `(x 4)` after the summing every time.

```
;; CPS-version of +
(define (+& a b continuation)
  (continuation (+ a b)))
```

Notice the &. It's used to indicate that the function takes one extra argument, the continuation. In CPS you define `call/cc` like this:

```
(define (call/cc& f& continuation)
  (define (exit& value actual-continuation)
    (continuation value))
  (f& exit& continuation))
```

Notice it's quite different from your version. It passes the exit function to `f&` and instead of using the passed `actual-continuation` that would do all the remaining computation it passes it to the continuation of `call/cc&` instead.

Now we can rewrite your program into this:

```
((lambda (x& halt-continuation) 
  (call/cc& (lambda (cont continuation)
              ((lambda (ingnored-undefined-value) (continuation 3))
               (set! x& cont)))
            (lambda (three)
              (+& 2 three (lambda (ignored-result)
                      (x& 4 halt-continuation))))))
 0 values)
```

`ignored-result` is `5` the first time and the infinite other times it calculates it with `4` `ignored-result` is `6`, just like in the non CPS version with `let`.

I use DrRacket which has a pretty darn good debugger and you can step and see exactly what is happening. I added a break point at the `+&` call and pressed `|>` and saw the variable `three` fist be `3` then `4` infinite times.

CPS isn't easy. `call/cc` gives us the benefits of CPS without making the code much harder to read. Implementing coroutines without `call/cc` would be challenging for me to write as I though it was quite complex to do it with `call/cc` to begin with, especially since you have a infinite loop if you are not very careful.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
What I want to do is to stock the continuation in the x variable that is define to 0 at the beginning so that when I use it, it just do a + 2 as in the example. But in your code x still is 0. How can I change that ?

Comment: @user1241025 `x&` does change since i `set!` it, just as in your original code. Or else you would get an apply error.